# Google Checkout HTML API for Hidden description field? or important information

Tags: html, api, google-checkout

I run a gold intangible electric goods which I am selling business.
Recently I came across some difficulties with PayPal where customers started doing chargebacks, I have now switched over to Google Checkout and now am making the website more secure against this type of fraud.

So I am collecting the user's IP address / hostname / user-agent / proxy information which I will send to credit card companies and FBI to resolve chargebacks from now on, I can't really start a database since my webiste doesn't use any databases just session based.

So I am sending for now the information as a secondary item.. with a price of 0.00$ (free). In base64 encoded format.

So how do I get the customer's information, but make it so the customer doesn't see this information, as first of all it may scare some customers.

The HTML Code my shopping website generates is like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="https://checkout.google.com/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/*Snipped*" accept-charset="utf-8">
<!-- Sell digital goods with email delivery of download instructions (with tax, no shipping) -->
<input type="hidden" name="hl" value="pt_BR">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description_1" value="Character: [5464564]: Tiberica">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="10,000 Gold [Nation]"><input type="hidden" name="item_price_1" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="item_currency_1" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.items.item-1.digital-content.display-disposition" value="PESSIMISTIC">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.items.item-1.digital-content.email-delivery" value="true">
<!-- Customer information -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Customer Information [Não é importante para o cliente]">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description_2" value="SVAgYWRkcmVzczogNzEuMTkwLjE3Ni40OQpSZW1vdGUgSG9zdDogcG9vbC03MS0xOTAtMTc2LTQ5Lm55Y21ueS5maW9zLnZlcml6b24ubmV0IC0gClVzZXIgQWdlbnQ6IE1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDUuMSkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM1LjIgKEtIVE1MLCBsaWtlIEdlY2tvKSBDaHJvbWUvMTUuMC44NzQuMTIxIFNhZmFyaS81MzUuMgpQcm94eT86IApQcm94eSBIb3N0PzogClByb3h5IFNlcnZlcj86IAo=">
<input type="hidden" name="item_price_2" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_currency_2" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.items.item-2.digital-content.display-disposition" value="PESSIMISTIC">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.items.item-2.digital-content.email-delivery" value="true">
<!-- No tax code -->
<!-- No shipping code -->
<input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="utf-8">
<input type="image" name="Google Checkout" alt="Fast checkout through Google" src="index_files/checkout_br.png" style="position: relative; top: -38px;left: 486px;">
</form>
```

[image: google checkout look]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use PHP (or ASP) and save the details to a database before forwarding to Google Checkout, then update the order with the transaction ID using callbacks?

Comment: Cannot run any sort of database on my webhost, trying to keep it cheap and lightweight. I am using PHP, which is how i get remote_host / getHostname(remote_host) etc.., I'm just trying to post hidden data to Google API.. I know there should be a way.. I remember reading about it on google checkout API something to do with Product Keys for Antivirus software vendors with google checkout.  So you're saying make google visit my website using some kind of id and get the information of my site and update the order, yeah would require some kind of flat storage, for something i can keep inside Google